# How to setup SMTP receiver, without postfix, sendmail or other complex software

Tags: linux, smtp, ssmtp

I have successfully configured ssmtp to send emails from our local server (using a single external mail account) for sending reports, build results and so on.

The other task is to let our software we are tesing to send email via this linux box, so that it is required to receive email via plain smtp, without authentication and for each received email execute ssmpt to resend this message. Is there any dedicated smtp-receiver-only software, capable to launch external utilities, upon receiving mails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

I would take a look at the [node.js SMTP server](https://gist.github.com/278814), but [Java Email Server](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/java/mailserver/) might be another option.

If you know Java at all, there is a SMTP receiver Dumbster built for testing applications that might work extremely well. Dumbster will receive the emails and let you deal with them how you'd like. Might not be what you're looking for.